# gloabal variables declared in cpp use in objective c

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using a cpp file in xcode project. In the cpp file I do the following

> ReadYML.h

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex_OR;

extern Vertex_OR Vertices_OR [100];

extern GLubyte Indices_OR [30];
```

> in ReadYML.cpp
>
> I assigned values for this.
>
> In view.m
>
> I declared "sample.h"

and tried accessing Vertices_OR and Indices_OR but am getting the below error?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_Indices_OR", referenced from:
      loadyml() in ReadYMLfile.o
  "_Vertices_OR", referenced from:
      loadyml() in ReadYMLfile.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the problem here? I need to use the global variable declared in "Sample.h" to access in view.m? Is it possible?

Comment: `view.m` appears uninvolved in this linker error; rather it looks like `ReadYMLFile.o`.

Answer (score 2):

```
extern Vertex_OR Vertices_OR [100];

extern GLubyte Indices_OR [30];
```

The `extern` means "hey, compiler, this symbol exists *somewhere*".  If you don't have a corresponding declaration like the following in some compilation unit somewhere, you'll get that link error (i.e. put this in the corresponding .m file somewhere):

```
Vertex_OR Vertices_OR [100];

GLubyte Indices_OR [30];
```

Comment: I took "I assigned values for this." as meaning he had initialized those variables correctly.